# Deploying Application suite to 8 environments using single pipeline in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, devops, continuous-deployment, jenkins-groovy

So basically i've Application Suite, which consist of 8 applications and i've 8 environments. i've created a pipeline for it but jenkins is giving this error: Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during class generation: Method code too large!

I've used a lot of when conditions please can anyone help me out! or provide me with a logic in which less which conditions are used.

Comment: The JVM has a size restriction on functions. You can just split the logic into multiple functions. Just out of curiousity, how many lines of code are we talking here?

Comment: @smelm, did that didn't help, 1300 lines i've cut it down to 700 still didn't work